# Ubuntu Black screen after installation

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I am trying to install ubuntu in my windows virtual box. The installation works smoothly but after it restarts there is only a black page with the ubuntu logo. I know this question has been asked a lot but nothing is working. My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series and my operating system is windows 10.
Things I have tried so far:

- Maxing my video memory to 128 MB
- Changing my graphics controller to all of the options
- remaking and reinstalling the virtual machine multiple times
- Changing the boot order
- Increasing my number of processors

Comment: I suggest that you start over and use the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox)

Comment: @Nmath I tried it. Did not work.